# sql server trying to rephrase a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I tried to do the following query in a different way.

```
SELECT distinct x FROM R as sx
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
(SELECT p.y FROM S as p )
EXCEPT
(SELECT sp.y FROM  R as sp WHERE sp.x = sx.x ) );
```

I have the following query that implements the division in sql server. I get syntax error and I don't know why. I have tables S(y) y->primary key, R(x,y) x->primary key, y->foreign key references S(y). x is supplier id and y is product id. I want to get the suppliers that sells all products.

Example of data

S y(1,2,3,4,5)

R x(101,101,102,102,102,102,102,103)
y(1,3,1,2,3,4,5,2)

output x(102)

```
SELECT x FROM R
EXCEPT
SELECT x FROM (
    SELECT x, y
    FROM (select x FROM R), S
    EXCEPT
    SELECT x, y FROM R
);
```

I get the following syntax error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: You are not providing an alias name for your derived tables, and what is the `, S` doing?

Comment: `x is supplier id and y is product id` then why did you make them `x` and `y` in the examples? `S(y) y => primary key` is fine notation in calculus and discrete mathematics, but in languages like SQL people typically chose meaningful table and variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count distinct values of y per each x and compare it to count of y in s

```
SELECT x 
FROM R
GROUP BY x
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM s)
```

EDIT:
.. and your 2nd query is giving you syntax errors because you have not put aliases on your sub-queries, which is needed when you join them.

```
SELECT x FROM R
EXCEPT
SELECT x FROM (
    SELECT x, y
    FROM (select x FROM R) r1, S
    EXCEPT
    SELECT x, y FROM R
) r2;
```